# Better solution as my ajax post?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following php code:

```
                            <tr>
                            <td class="vacancyID">
                                <?php echo $vacancyID; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleLongTitle">
                                <?php echo $roleLongTitle; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleRequirements">
                                <?php echo $roleRequirements; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleResponsibilities">
                                <?php echo $roleResponsibilities; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="roleQualifications">
                                <?php echo $roleQualifications; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="closeDate">
                                <?php
                                    //Convert the mySQL date to PHP date
                                    echo convertToDate($closeDate);
                                ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
```

And the following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var btn = $('a.btn-primary'); 
var closeDate = $('td.closeDate');
var applyBtn = $('<input type="button" value=" Apply " class="toggleButton" />');
//var applyLnk = $('<a href="index.php" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Apply</a>');

//Rmove a link
btn.remove();

//Add button
applyBtn.insertAfter(closeDate);
//applyBtn.appendTo(closeDate);
  //applyLnk.insertAfter(closeDate);

$('.toggleButton').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = {
            vacancyID: obj.find('td.vacancyID').text(),
            closeDate: obj.find('td.closeDate').text(),
            roleLongTitle: obj.find('td.roleLongTitle').text(),
            roleRequirements: obj.find('td.roleRequirements').text(),
            roleResponsibilities: obj.find('td.roleResponsibilities').text(),
            roleQualifications: obj.find('td.roleQualifications').text(),
        }

         //Post the data to the page
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: 'vacancy.php',
             data: data,
             success: function(data){
                window.location.assign("applyForVacancy.php");
             }
        });
        //console.log(data);
    });

});
```

Is there any way for me to make this better?  I have tried many option and this one is the only one that's working and that can get access to those posted values based on the button I clicked.

Comment: I forgot to add, that I use the vacancy page to create session id's for the vacancy ID and things like that.

Comment: i think you want https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how do you want something. Is it like shortening code?

Comment: @Willem When you forget to add something, click the "edit" link to add it, rather than putting it in a comment. Comments are disposable and shouldn't be used for anything important to the question.

Comment: What kind of improvement are you looking for? It looks pretty simple and clear to me. You could replace the list of properties in the object with a loop that goes through all the TDs and constructs the object dynamically, but that's not really very important.

Comment: Since the php variables are constant within the HTML/jQuery, why not let PHP put them straight into the jQuery code? (Not applicable if the jQuery comes from a separate .js file of course.) Something like: 
`var data = {
vacancyID: <?=$vacancyID ?>, closeDate: '<?=convertToDate($closeDate) ?>',  roleLongTitle: '<?=$roleLongTitle ?>,  ...etc ... }`

Comment: They are not constant as there can be any number of vacancies and the user can then click a button of any of the vacancies to apply to any one of them in the list.  It all depends on how many open vacancies there are coming from the DB query.